# Как расшифровать крифтографический хэш "fernet"

Tags: python

У меня имеется последствие от кодировки fernet, вида:`gAAAAABeL1Xd9czJCitEf_qZ5xJN4lBP4Zy3kC4eV-EVxGOBRK0WR9cX0d...`

как получить исходную строку?

Comment: Вы знаете, что криптографический хеш по определению это необратимая функция?

Comment: Если я правильно нагуглил, то это не хэш, а симметричный шифр. https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/. Так что надо узнать исходный пароль и расшифровать. Никаких других осмысленных способов нет по определению шифрования